# ¿Cómo mostrar imágenes de un directorio fuera de mi aplicación (java)?

Tags: java, html5, rutas, img, src

Trato de mostrar las imágenes de un proyecto web en java pero de un directorio fuera de mi aplicación.

Es decir la aplicación lo tengo en el siguiente directorio

```
/opt/payara41/glassfish/nodes/localhost-domain1/i0.local.instance/applications/SistemaArchivoIU
```

y las imágenes lo estoy almacenando en el siguiente directorio

```
/var/payaradata/sga
```

del mismo servidor web, el problema que se me presenta es que no se muestra las imágenes que están almacenadas en esa dirección el código es el siguiente

```
<img id="1imgVisualizar" src="/var/payaradata/sga/1Reee.jpg">
```

Me podrían ayudar a poder visualizar los archivos que están en una dirección fuera de mi aplicación.

Comment: ¿De dónde cuelga el directorio `/var/payaradata/sga`?  Tendrás que navegar con `../` (para ir hacia atrás en el directorio) o con `/` (para ir hacia adelante)

Comment: ¿Que servidor web estas utilizando?¿En la configuración del servidor como esta configurado el docroot que directorio tiene?Porque si esta así **/var/payaradata/** lo único que tendrías que hacer es esto **src="1Reee.jpg"** . Otra opción podría ser que tu armes la ruta completa: 
 src="http://localhost:8080:/micontexto/var/payaradata/sga/1Reee.jpg">

Comment: La configuración del servidor del docroot no te podría decir como esta ya que a mi solo me dan las direcciones de los servidores para subir la app en esta caso me dieron la dirección del payara server para subir la aplicación y una ruta para poder guardar las imágenes ya coloque rutas absolutas y relativas ya navegue con ../ pero nada que se muestra los archivos.

Comment: No había visto que estabas utilizando glassfish, ¿Ya intentaste solo con el nombre de la imagen? También podrías intentar así: **var/payaradata/sga/1Reee.jpg**  y **sga/1Reee.jpg**. De otra forma te tendían que decir como accesar al docroot porque es muy diferente el directorio físico del servidor al del web que se configura en glassfish porque también le pudieron poner un alias o atrás pueden ponerle un apache web.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo resolví agregando una configuración en el glassfish- web con el alternatedocroot